# Javascript Validate on input change, only submit when Submit button clicked

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-validate, validation

I have a form on my site. When the submit button is clicked, a function runs to get the contents of each field, validate the contents based on RegEx and other requirements, and then if everything looks fine, the form is submitted via Ajax to a .php mailer.

**I would like the form to validate automatically when the input field values change, OR when the input field loses focus (I have no preference, either would be great) AND THEN I would like the form to submit ONLY when the user clicks the Submit button on the form.** If the user clicks the Submit button BEFORE all fields are valid, I do NOT want the form to submit.

Here's my code:

```
    //contact form validation   
$(function(){
    $('.error').hide();
    // hide error messages onchange
    $("#contact-form").change(function(){
        $('.error').hide(); 
        $("label#name_error").hide(); 
        $("label#invalid_error").hide(); 
        $("label#email_error").hide(); 
        $("label#invalid_phone_error").hide(); 
        $("label#phone_error").hide(); 
        $("label#zip_error").hide();
    });

    // validate fields on click
    $(".cool-button").click(function(){
        $('.error').hide(); 
        $("label#name_error").hide(); 
        $("label#invalid_error").hide(); 
        $("label#email_error").hide(); 
        $("label#invalid_phone_error").hide(); 
        $("label#phone_error").hide(); 
        $("label#zip_error").hide(); 

        var name=$("input#contact_name").val();
        var email=$("input#contact_email").val();
        var emailRegEx =/^([a-zA-Z0-9])(([a-zA-Z0-9])*([\._-])?([a-zA-Z0-9]))*@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+(\.))+([a-zA-Z]{2,4})+$/
        var phone=$("input#contact_phone").val();
        var phone=phone.replace(/\s+-/g, "");
        var phoneRegEx = /^(1-?)?\s?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|\s?-?[2-9]\d{2})-?\s?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/
        var zip=$("input#contact_zip").val();
        var best_time=$("input#contact_best_time").val();
        var message=$("textarea#contact_message").val();
        var timestamp=$("input#timestamp").val();

        if(name==""){
            $("label#name_error").show();
            $("input#contact_name").focus();return false;
            }
        if(email==""){
            $("label#email_error").show();
            $("input#contact_email").focus();return false;
            }
        if (document.getElementById('contact_email').value.search(emailRegEx )==-1) {
            $("label#invalid_error").show();
            $("input#contact_email").focus();return false;
            }
        if(phone==""){
            $("label#phone_error").show();
            $("input#contact_phone").focus();return false;
            }
        if (document.getElementById('contact_phone').value.search(phoneRegEx )==-1) {
            $("label#invalid_phone_error").show();
            $("input#contact_phone").focus();return false;
            }
        if(zip==""){
            $("label#zip_error").show();
            $("input#contact_zip").focus();return false;
            }
        if(message==""){
            $("label#message_error").show();
            $("textarea#contact_message").focus();return false;
            }
        else {
var dataString='contact_name='+name+'&contact_email='+email+'&contact_phone='+phone+'&contact_zip='+zip+'&contact_best_time='+best_time+'&timestamp='+timestamp+'&contact_message='+encodeURIComponent(message);
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"php/contact.php",
        data:dataString,
        success:function(){$('#contact-form').html("<div id='message'></div>");$('#message').html("<h3>Message Sent</h3>").append("<p>Thank you for contacting us. We'll be in touch. <br /><br />If you have any further questions, you can always email us at info@wirecrafters.com or call us at 800-924-9473</p>").hide().fadeIn(800,function(){$('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/submit2.png' />");});}});
        }
        return false;
    });

});
```

AND HERE IS THE HTML and PHP CODE FOR THE FORM

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="#">
                          <p class="form-subscr-field">
                            <label for="contact_name" id="contact_name_label">Your name: *</label>
                            <input id="contact_name" type="text" name="contact_name" class="inputbox" size="10" required/>
                            <label class="error error-tip" for="contact_name" id="name_error" style="display: none; ">Please enter your name.</label>
                          </p>
                          <p class="form-subscr-field">
                            <label for="contact_email" id="contact_email_label">E-mail Address: *</label>
                            <input id="contact_email" type="email" name="contact_email" class="inputbox" size="10" required/>
                            <label class="error error-tip" for="contact_email" id="email_error" style="display: none; ">Please enter your email address.</label>
                            <label class="error error-tip" for="contact_email" id="invalid_error" style="display: none; ">Invalid email address.</label>
                          </p>
                          <fieldset class="w50">
                          <p class="form-subscr-field rowElem left">
                            <label for="contact_phone" id="contact_phone_label">Phone: *</label>
                            <input id="contact_phone" type="tel" name="contact_phone" class="inputbox"  size="10" required minlength="9"/>
                            <label class="error error-tip" for="contact_phone" id="phone_error" style="display: none; ">Please enter your phone number.</label>
                            <label class="error error-tip" for="contact_phone" id="invalid_phone_error" style="display: none; ">Please enter a valid phone number.</label>
                          </p>
                           </fieldset>
                           <fieldset class="w50">
                          <p class="form-subscr-field rowElem right">
                            <label for="contact_zip" id="contact_zip_label">Zip Code: *</label>
                            <input id="contact_zip" type="text" name="contact_zip" class="inputbox"  size="10" required minlength="5"/>
                            <label class="error error-tip" for="contact_zip" id="zip_error" style="display: none; ">Please enter your shipping zip code.</label>
                          </p>
                           </fieldset>
                          <p class="form-subscr-field">
                            <label for="contact_best_time" id="contact_best_time_label">Best time to Contact:</label>
                            <input id="contact_best_time" type="text" name="contact_best_time" class="inputbox"  size="10" />
                          </p>
                          <p class="form-subscr-field">
                            <label for="contact_message" id="comment_label">Your message: *</label>
                            <textarea id="contact_message" name="contact_message" rows="8" cols="30" required minlength="2"></textarea>
                            <label class="error error-tip" for="contact_message" id="message_error" style="display: none; ">This field is required.</label>
                          </p>
                          <input type="hidden" id="timestamp" name="timestamp" value="<?php
$hourdiff = "2"; // hours diff btwn server and local time
$insertdate = date("l, d F Y h:i a",time() + ($hourdiff * 3600));
print ("$insertdate");
?>" />
                          <div class="submit-contact">
                            <p>
                              <input type="submit" name="submit" class="cool-button csbutton-color spot-action" id="contact_button" value="Submit" />
                            </p>
                          </div>
                        </form>
```

Comment: Just curious; you validate on the server as well yes?

Comment: The problem here with validating immediately is that you will be showing errors for the fields with no values yet. You have to break this up either manually which would be ugly, or with some kind of plugin/library (which you could write yourself).

Comment: @Jeffery: Just to make sure I understand your question, explain what you mean validating on the server as well?

Comment: Its very possible for a user to disable JavaScript and thus bypass validation, so validating on both the client and server is generally good practice.

Comment: What I really want is the first part of my function to work when the input box loses focus, and then IF the first part of the function says everything is ok, IF the user clicks the Submit button, the form submits (executing the code in the ELSE statement)

Answer (score 0):

You should use some kind of validator plugin. Personally I've used jquery tools form validator and it works great.. There are others as well. Check this:
http://flowplayer.org/tools/validator/

I also use a plugin that I built which will take a form and submit it via ajax, and there are some out there which work real similar to mine:

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Is one example. This allows you to make the form in normal html and it will submit the form to the form's action url, and it will build the forms values the same way the browser would if you submitted without ajax. Thus, to whatever your backend script is the form fields submit just as if you hadn't used ajax.

Since this seems like too much work for you, let me show you what your code looks like with and without it.

Without (look above at your js).

No assuming your form looks like this (simplified)

```
<form method="POST" action="php/contact.php">
  <label for="contact_name">Name</label>
  <input name="contact_name" id="contact_name" />
  <br />
  <label for="contact_email">Email</label>
  <input name="contact_email" id="contact_email" />
  <br />
  <label for="contact_phone">Phone</label>
  <input name="contact_phone" id="contact_phone" />
  <br />
  <label for="contact_zip">Zip</label>
  <input name="contact_zip" id="contact_zip" />
  <br />
  <label for="contact_best_time">Best time for Contact</label>
  <input name="contact_best_time" id="contact_best_time" />
  <br />
  <label for="contact_message">Message:</label>
  <input name="contact_message" id="contact_message" />
</form>
```

Now thats probably similar to what it looks like now without all the extra html for formatting.

If you used both the validator and the ajax form validator you have to make hardly any changes. Let me show them.

With the validator and ajax form you would then have this:

```
<form method="POST" action="php/contact.php" class="use-validator ajax-form">
  <label for="contact_name">Name</label>
  <input name="contact_name" id="contact_name" />
  <br />
  <label for="contact_email">Email</label>
  <input name="contact_email" id="contact_email" type="email" required="required" />
  <br />
  <label for="contact_phone">Phone</label>
  <input name="contact_phone" id="contact_phone" type="phone" />
  <br />
  <label for="contact_zip">Zip</label>
  <input name="contact_zip" id="contact_zip" required="required" />
  <br />
  <label for="contact_best_time">Best time for Contact</label>
  <input name="contact_best_time" id="contact_best_time" required="required" />
  <br />
  <label for="contact_message">Message:</label>
  <textarea name="contact_message" id="contact_message" required="required"></textarea>
</form>
```

Then your js would be:

```
$.tools.validator.fn("[type=phone]", "Invalid phone number", function(input, value) {   
   var phoneRegEx = /^(1-?)?\s?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|\s?-?[2-9]\d{2})-?\s?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/ 
   return value.test(phoneRegEx);
});

$("form.use-validator").validator();

$("form.ajax-form").ajaxForm({
 success:function(){$('#contact-form').html("<div id='message'></div>");$('#message').html("<h3>Message Sent</h3>").append("<p>Thank you for contacting us. We'll be in touch. <br /><br />If you have any further questions, you can always email us at info@wirecrafters.com or call us at 800-924-9473</p>").hide().fadeIn(800,function(){$('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/submit2.png' />");});}});
});
```

And any custom validators you make you can reuse on other forms..

And then you may need some custom error messages but that's it.. You can delete all that other js code you have.

Comment: I updated my answer. I can't tell from your code exactly how errors look for your form but I've found that with the valiator plugin and a bit of work this will save you tons of code. And then the ajax form simplifies the process of submitting the form so you don't have to manually build the post/get values to send.

Comment: My errors are styled with CSS and look like jquery tooltips. They have certain classes attached to them for styling, and then are shown or hidden depending on validation. If I use the updated code you included above, do I have to include/attach a "validate" file Or anything?

Comment: If you have custom validation then you would need to make a validator for each. You could actually use the validator above in conjunction with the way way you are doing it now, but you would have to do a bit of work. Can you include in your original message what the html looks like for your form? I'm cursious how/where the errors show up.

Comment: I edited my original question and included the code for the form. Any help would be great! The javascript shows or hides the hidden labels, and they are styled with CSS

Comment: I think what you would want to use is http://flowplayer.org/tools/validator/#effects
I wrote one for the site I built which would put the error in a div next to the input. Since each input was wrapped in a div I was able to position the errors in a way that didn't use absolute positioning and and thus wouldn't overlap other things on the page. I can provide you with the code for that if you want.

Comment: I changed the code to the new code I tweaked to get basically (kind of) what I want. Maybe you or someone could help me condense it so it is not as lengthy, and is reusable with diff forms on my site with different input ids?

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly achieved with the `keyup` function.
Whenever a key is released, a function can be called to make sure that all the fields are accurate, and if so, left the user know in an unobtrusive way. In your case, you could have the submit button disabled unless all the fields are correct.

Note: You should never modify currently edited text fields with the function, or do anything else that will prove to be an annoyance to the user ;)

---

Edit: I modified the code to validate every time a key is lifted for all input fields.
I'm not fluent in JQuery, so I did it with vanilla Javascript. If need be, it should be pretty easy to convert.

```
$(function(){


  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

  for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

    inputs[i].addEventListener("keyup", function(){validate()}, true);

  }


  $('.error').hide();
  $(".cool-button").click(function(){validate()});

  function validate() {
                          $('.error').hide(); 
                          $("label#name_error").hide(); 
                          $("label#invalid_error").hide(); 
                          $("label#email_error").hide(); 
                          $("label#invalid_phone_error").hide(); 
                          $("label#phone_error").hide(); 
                          $("label#zip_error").hide(); 

                          var name=$("input#contact_name").val();
                          var email=$("input#contact_email").val();
                          var emailRegEx =/^([a-zA-Z0-9])(([a-zA-Z0-9])*([\._-])?([a-zA-Z0-9]))*@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+(\.))+([a-zA-Z]{2,4})+$/
                          var phone=$("input#contact_phone").val();
                          var phone=phone.replace(/\s+-/g, "");
                          var phoneRegEx = /^(1-?)?\s?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|\s?-?[2-9]\d{2})-?\s?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/
                          var zip=$("input#contact_zip").val();
                          var best_time=$("input#contact_best_time").val();
                          var message=$("textarea#contact_message").val();
                          var timestamp=$("input#timestamp").val();

                          if(name==""){
                          $("label#name_error").show();$("input#contact_name").focus();return false;
                          }
                          if(email==""){
                          $("label#email_error").show();$("input#contact_email").focus();return false;
                          }
                          if (document.getElementById('contact_email').value.search(emailRegEx )==-1) {
                          $("label#invalid_error").show();$("input#contact_email").focus();return false;
                          }
                          if(phone==""){
                          $("label#phone_error").show();$("input#contact_phone").focus();return false;
                          }
                          if (document.getElementById('contact_phone').value.search(phoneRegEx )==-1) {
                          $("label#invalid_phone_error").show();$("input#contact_phone").focus();return false;
                          }
                          if(zip==""){
                          $("label#zip_error").show();$("input#contact_zip").focus();return false;
                          }
                          if(message==""){
                          $("label#message_error").show();$("textarea#contact_message").focus();return false;
                          }
                          else {
                          var dataString='contact_name='+name+'&contact_email='+email+'&contact_phone='+phone+'&contact_best_time='+best_time+'&contact_zip='+zip+'&timestamp='+timestamp+'&contact_message='+encodeURIComponent(message);
                          $.ajax({
                                 type:"POST",
                                 url:"php/contact.php",
                                 data:dataString,
                                 success:function(){$('#contact-form').html("<div id='message'></div>");$('#message').html("<h3>Message Sent</h3>").append("<p>Thank you for contacting us. We'll be in touch. <br /><br />If you have any further questions, you can always email us at info@wirecrafters.com or call us at 800-924-9473</p>").hide().fadeIn(800,function(){$('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/submit2.png' />");});}});
                          }
                          return false;
                          };
  });
```

Comment: IS there a way I can just modify the code I already have above? I have custom jQuery tooltips as validation messages already built in.

I'd like to do everything BEFORE the "else" statement when the input fields lose focus, and then perform the "else" action ONLY when all of the fields are valid, AND ONLY when the user clicks the Submit button.

Comment: it may seem like a lot of work or code to add but jquery tools validator is a small plugin and will save you tons of code if you are doing the above everytime you want to submit a form. A form plugin will save you from having to manually serialize the form (which is what you did above as well)

Comment: To redo all of the forms on the site at this point would be a HUGE undertaking :(
Is there not a way to just split the function into two different things where:

Function 1 - Gets the value on blur or on change from the input field, and then validates, and throws the popup message if incorrect.

Function 2 - If the first function sets some variable (or whatever better way to do it) to "valid" or something, then when the user clicks the Submit button, the form is submitted?

Comment: You may be able to apply the keyboard function to the forum, so you would only need to do it once. Not positive though. EDIT: you could also loop through all of the elements and append an event listener.

Comment: Is this something I could do with my original code shown above? If so, show me? :)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot right now. All you need to do is loop through all the input tags in your forum, and bind the validation function with `addEventListener` to the tags.

Comment: All set. Let me know if there are any problems.

Comment: Thanks... :)
Ok here's the problems I ran into with what you gave me...

1. As soon as there is ANYTHING that is valid in the field, it automatically switches focus to the next field (not allowing me to fluently continue what I'm typing unless I click back in the field.

2.It sent the message before I was finished

3. It attempted to send several times :(

Comment: Remove any `focus()` function calls, as well as anything else that happens automatically (except re-enabling the button). You shouldn't ever change the focus or text of validated elements unless the user knowingly wishes to do so (usability-wise).

Answer (score 0):

I tend to break validation down for each input, which makes this stuff a lot easier. You could also use a jQuery plugin, which would probably be more modular in the long run.

That said, I would do it like this ([working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmvVa/)):

```
//contact form validation 
$(function() {
    $('.error').hide(); //hide all errors
    function fieldHasValue(field, label) {
        var value = field.val().trim(); //Grab value without leading or trailing whitespace
        if (value.length > 0) {
            label.hide();
        } else {
            label.show();
            field.focus();
        }
        return (value.length > 0);
    }
    function nameIsValid() {
        return fieldHasValue($("input#contact_name"), $("label#name_error"));
    }
    function emailIsValid() {
        var email = $("input#contact_email").val().trim(); //Grab value without leading or trailing whitespace
        var emailRegEx = /^([a-zA-Z0-9])(([a-zA-Z0-9])*([\._\-])?([a-zA-Z0-9]))*@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+(\.))+([a-zA-Z]{2,4})+$/;
        var isValid = (email.length > 0) && email.match(emailRegEx);
        if (isValid) {
            $("label#email_error").hide();
            $("label#invalid_error").hide();
        } else if (email.length > 0) {
            $("label#invalid_error").show();
            $("input#contact_email").focus();
        } else {
            $("label#email_error").show();
            $("input#contact_email").focus();
        }
        return isValid;
    }
    function phoneIsValid() {
        var phone = $("input#contact_phone").val().replace(/\s+-/g, "").trim(); //Grab value without leading or trailing whitespace and replace [whitespace -] with an empty string.
        var phoneRegEx = /^(1-?)?\s?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|\s?-?[2-9]\d{2})-?\s?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/;
        var isValid = (phone.length > 0) && phone.match(phoneRegEx);
        if (isValid) {
            $("label#invalid_phone_error").hide();
            $("label#phone_error").hide();
        } else if (phone.length > 0) {
            $("label#invalid_phone_error").show();
            $("input#contact_phone").focus();
        } else {
            $("label#phone_error").show();
            $("input#contact_phone").focus();
        }
        return isValid;
    }
    function zipIsValid() {
        return fieldHasValue($("input#contact_zip"), $("label#zip_error"));
    }
    function messageIsValid() {
        return fieldHasValue($("textarea#contact_message"), $("label#message_error"));
    }
    function bestTimeIsValid() {
        return fieldHasValue($("input#contact_best_time"), $("label#best_time_error"));
    }
    function allInputsAreValid() {
        var validName = nameIsValid();
        var validEmail = emailIsValid();
        var validPhone = phoneIsValid();
        var validZIP = zipIsValid();
        var validMessage = messageIsValid();
        var validBestTime = bestTimeIsValid();
        var isValid = validName && validEmail && validPhone && validZIP && validMessage && validBestTime;
        return isValid;
    }
    $("input#contact_name").on('change blur', nameIsValid);
    $("input#contact_email").on('change blur', emailIsValid);
    $("input#contact_phone").on('change blur', phoneIsValid);
    $("input#contact_zip").on('change blur', zipIsValid);
    $("textarea#contact_message").on('change blur', messageIsValid);
    $("input#contact_best_time").on('change blur', bestTimeIsValid);
    $("input#contact_button").on('click', function (e) {
        var timestamp = $("input#timestamp").val();

        if (allInputsAreValid()) {
            var dataString = 'contact_name=' + name + '&contact_email=' + email + '&contact_phone=' + phone + '&contact_zip=' + zip + '&contact_best_time=' + best_time + '&timestamp=' + timestamp + '&contact_message=' + encodeURIComponent(message);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "php/contact.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function() {
                    $('#contact-form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
                    $('#message').html("<h3>Message Sent</h3>").append("<p>Thank you for contacting us. We'll be in touch. <br /><br />If you have any further questions, you can always email us at info@wirecrafters.com or call us at 800-924-9473</p>").hide().fadeIn(800, function() {
                        $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/submit2.png' />");
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```